# Inconsistency in Tables - Galera Cluster

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

MariaDB cluster Version : mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.24-MariaDB,

I have a two node + arbitrator cluster which is live and replicating data across nodes.

Unfortunately we found some inconsistency in some of the tables in Databases.

For instance:

Node1:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select count(*) from example_db.reports;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      299 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Node2:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select count(*) from example_db.reports;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      285 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note: Not find any noticeable errors in mysql error log

What could be the reasons for these kind of inconsistency ?

Is that a bug or a known issues ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any bugs in this *very critical* area.

In Galera clusters, you *must* check for errors after all statements, *including* `COMMIT`.  (This is different than in ordinary replication.)

All tables are InnoDB, correct?

Comment: All are innodb.